# Create a DbGeography Polygon from a collection of DbGeography Points

Tags: entity-framework, geospatial

Can anyone tell me how I can create a DbGeography object of type 'Polygon' from a Collection of DbGeography objects of type 'POINT'

So far I've got this which creates the polygon but I'm missing how the initial step.

```
1. DbGeography multipoint = DbGeography.MultiPointFromText("MULTIPOINT(53.095124 -0.864716, 53.021255 -1.337128, 52.808019 -1.345367, 52.86153 -1.018524)", 4326)

2. DbGeometry temp_multipoint = DbGeometry.MultiPointFromBinary(multipoint.AsBinary(), 4326)

3. DbGeography polygon = DbGeography.PolygonFromBinary(temp_multipoint.ConvexHull.AsBinary(), 4326); (RESULT)
```

The problem is creating the initial multipoint geography object from a list of DbGeography(POINTS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did eventually find out how to create a polygon from multiple points without having to create it from WKT. The below explanation is slightly simplified but nonetheless

```
    var PolygonFromMultiplePoints = new DbGeography();

    using (var db = new LocationContext())
    {
        //Select Locations known to be within a certain area which should define the polygon.
        foreach (var item in db.Locations)
        {
            PolygonFromMultiplePoints.Union(item.GeoLocation);
        }
    }            
    var temp_multipointgeometry = DbGeometry.MultiPointFromBinary(PolygonFromMultiplePoints.AsBinary(), DbGeometry.DefaultCoordinateSystemId);            
    PolygonFromMultiplePoints = DbGeography.PolygonFromBinary(temp_multipointgeometry.ConvexHull.AsBinary(), DbGeography.DefaultCoordinateSystemId);
```

Code sample assumes that you already have a collection of dbgeography stored as points in the database. My database information was derived from importing locations from GeoNames.

Comment: for my case it was better to use the MultiPointFromText method as I had 90,000 points and using union was slow, and that I only needed the convex hull of the result so the order of the points didn't matter.  MultiPointFromText was under a second whereas using union took over an hour.

Answer (score 6):

Create each point as a DbGeography object using WKT:

```
DbGeography point1 = DbGeography.FromText("POINT(53.095124 -0.864716)", 4326);
DbGeography point2 = DbGeography.FromText("POINT(53.021255 -1.337128)", 4326);
DbGeography point3 = DbGeography.FromText("POINT(52.808019 -1.345367)", 4326);
...
DbGeography polygon = DbGeography.PolygonFromText("POLYGON((53.095124 -0.864716, 53.021255 -1.337128, 52.808019 -1.345367, 53.095124 -0.864716))", 4326);
```

Two things to note:

- The WKT format is Longitude then Latitude, not the more intuitive Lat, Long
- For a polygon, the LAST point must match the FIRST point to "close it off"

Hope this helps - I also battled to learn the polygon stuff!

See this article for extra tips on the WKT format: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text

Comment: Thanks for you input, however it's not quite what I'm looking for as I already have all the points in a database as DbGeography fields.
I have since the question found another solution which is will add to this question when I get the time.

Comment: The classic "I have <your exact problem>, can anyone help? NevermindIsolveditbye"

Answer (score 0):

You should really do it in C#, adding points in an iterative way for a couple of reasons:

- You need to ensure that the end position is the same as the start.
- You need to ensure that the points are added clockwise, due to ring orientation. You can flip the ring around and go counterclockwise (sqlGeography.ReorientObject();).

You're dealing with spatial data, but the construction of complex shapes was never meant for T-SQL. At worst put it in a CLR function.